# Efficient way to enter link on phone

Tags: mobile, hyperlinks, sharing

I am currently working on a web app that requires users to type the given link on their phone's browser to access the info. I am thinking of putting in a QR code.

Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: QR code can be an option, do not write it off

Comment: HI thanx for all your input. I did some research and found out that the market (Malaysia) QR codes are pretty popular. So decided o go with both a url shortener and also QR code.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend not to put a QR code. The reason is for reading the QR code you have to be dependent on a third party app. If the user doesn't have the app, the whole purpose is defeated.

Instead you can provide a tiny url which will reduce the typing effort.

I prefer google's url shortener

https://goo.gl/

Comment: If you use an URL shortener like Google's or Bitly.com they generate QR codes too, so you can cover both bases. I would certainly avoid relying on QR codes though.

Answer (score 0):

A helpful flow chart that helps you decide if you need a flowchart or not :)

[image]

Source: https://econsultancy.com/blog/64891-six-mobile-marketing-alternatives-to-qr-codes/

Can you share the link with the users in their inbox so as to reduce the user's typing effort?

It would help if you can elaborate on who would the users be and how and when would they require the link.